# Textblob logic help. NaiveBayesClassifier

Tags: django, python-2.7, naivebayes, textblob

I am building a simple classifier that determines sentences whether they are positive. this is how i train the classifier using textblob.

```
train = [
     'i love your website', 'pos',
     'i really like your site', 'pos',
     'i dont like your website', 'neg',
     'i dislike your site', 'neg
]

cl.NaiveBayesClassifier(train)

#im clasifying text from twitter using tweepy and it goes like this and 
stored into the databse and using the django to save me doing all the hassle 
of  the backend

class StdOutListener(StreamListener)
def __init__(self)
    self.raw_tweets = []
    self.raw_teets.append(jsin.loads(data)
def on_data(self, data):
    tweets = Htweets() # connection to the database
    for x in self.raw_data:
        tweets.tweet_text = x['text']

        cl.classify(x['text'])

        if classify(x['text]) == 'pos'
            tweets.verdict = 'pos'
        elif classify(x['text]) == 'neg':
             tweets.verdict = 'neg'
        else:
             tweets.verdict = 'normal'
```

the logic seem pretty straightforward but when i trained the classifier which one is positive or negative it should saved the verdict along with the tweet into the database.

But this doesnt seem the case and i have been altering the logic in many ways and still unsuccesful. The problem is if the tweet is positive or negative yes the algorithm does recognise that they are.

However i want it to save 'normal' if they are not and it is not doing this. I recognise the classifier only recognises two things positive or negative, but surely it should also identify if a text does not falls within this category.

How is this possible when using textblob. sample alternative logic and advise would be great  thanks.

Comment: the usual way to achieve that would be creating a third class: neutral, with examples.

Comment: i dont think textblob accepts third class it gives a too many values unpack error

Comment: then you could create two binary classifiers, one neg vs neutral, the other pos vs neutral. Neutral can either mean "no sentiment expressed" or "balanced sentiment" (as much pos as neg). Thus it is possible that the same instance is classified both as positive AND negative by their respective classifiers (up to you to decide if that would be neutral or a fourth category, balanced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classify would always give you an answer with maximum probability, so you shall use the `prob_classify` method to get probability distribution of your category labels. On observing the probability distribution, and setting up proper confidence thresholds, you will start getting 'neutral' categorization too with a good training set.
Example with a minimal training set to reflect on the concept, for actual usage you shall use a big training set :

```
>>> train
[('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'), ('this is an amazing place!', 'pos'), ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'), ('this is my best work.', 'pos'), ('what an awesome view', 'pos'), ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'), ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'), ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'), ('he is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'), ('my boss is horrible.', 'neg')]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(train)
[('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
 ('this is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
 ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
 ('this is my best work.', 'pos'),
 ('what an awesome view', 'pos'),
 ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
 ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
 ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
 ('he is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
 ('my boss is horrible.', 'neg')]
>>> train2 = [('science is a subject','neu'),('this is horrible food','neg'),('glass has water','neu')]
>>> train = train+train2
>>> from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
>>> cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
>>> prob_dist = cl.prob_classify("I had a horrible day,I am tired")
>>> (prob_dist.prob('pos'),prob_dist.prob('neg'),prob_dist.prob('neu'))
(0.01085221171283812, 0.9746799258978173, 0.014467862389343378)
>>> 
>>> prob_dist = cl.prob_classify("This is a subject")
>>> (prob_dist.prob('pos'),prob_dist.prob('neg'),prob_dist.prob('neu'))
(0.10789848368588585, 0.14908905046805337, 0.7430124658460614)
```